# How to set proxy configuration for vault client when using quarkus-vault?

Tags: proxy, quarkus, vault

Using quarkus-vault to retrieve secrets from our openshift, we need to set a proxy to be able to reach the vault server that is outside of the cluster.
Is it possible to do it in application.properties?

We already set proxy for rest-client and oidc-client in application.properties.
Proxy works fine for oidc and rest-client but request to vault fails with timeout

```
%prod.quarkus.rest-client.proxy-address=my-proxy:3128 
%prod.quarkus.rest-client.non-proxy-hosts=${REDIS_HOST} 
%prod.quarkus.oidc-client.proxy.host=my-proxy 
%prod.quarkus.oidc-client.proxy.port=3128
```

We also tried to configure https proxy via -Dhttps.proxyHost / proxyPort in JVM ... without success.

Thanks in advance.
Patrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, while reading the qaurkus-vault code, I found that the proxy configuration was missing.
So I proposed a Pull Request to manage this configuration.
This PR is merged in [quarkus-vault version 3.1.0](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-vault/releases/tag/3.1.0). I hope this version will soon be integrated into the quarkus platform.